# È «'sta» ormai italiano standard?

Tags: orthography

Sembra che l'uso del «'», già diffuso in posizione postposta come in «po'» o «gliel'ho», si stia diffondendo anche in posizione anteposta per indicare un'elisione/troncamento.

Per esempio, l'altro giorno ho letto:

> Putin, fammi 'sta grazia, chiudi il gas.

Allora sono a chiedere: È ormai italiano standard usare, quando si ritiene sia il caso, «'sta» al posto di «questa»?

Se sì, quand'è il caso di usare l'una piuttosto che l'altra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le forme elise *'sto*, *'sta*, *'sti*, *'ste* sono comprensibili da qualunque parlante ma restano colloquiali. Solo in un contesto estremamente formale potrebbero essere considerate "irritanti", di solito passano abbastanza inosservate nel parlato e non è affatto insolito sentirle usare anche in un contesto professionale. Nello scritto si usano quasi esclusivamente per riportare il discorso parlato.

L'origine centromeridionale dell'elisione non influenza più né la diffusione né il "suono" di queste parole. Un parlante settentrionale probabilmente sa che a Roma e in molte zone del Mezzogiorno in dialetto *questo*, *questa* ecc. sono sostituiti dalle forme elise ma non per questo si sentirà a disagio nell'utilizzarle in italiano.

Diverso è il caso di espressioni come *stavolta*, *stasera*, *stamane*, che non sono colloquiali e possono essere usate sempre (e vanno scritte senza apostrofo). Forse il fatto che queste parole siano standard anche nello scritto contribuisce a nobilitare anche *'sta* e i suoi fratelli.

Answer (score 9):

*'sto* in luogo di *questo* è un'elisione dialettale, originaria delle regioni del Centro e Sud Italia. Viene usata solo nell'italiano parlato, e sempre in contesti informali e amichevoli, perché viene considerata indice di un linguaggio popolare (mentre "questo" ha una connotazione neutrale).

As a *rule of thumb*, direi che si usa "'sta" quando si vuole evidenziare il registro basso della conversazione; nel dubbio, conviene usare "questa" per evitare di irritare l'interlocutore che si aspetta un tono più formale.