# "Ormai" versus "adesso"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, adverbs

Questi avverbi, "ormai" e "adesso", hanno sfumature diverse che mi sfuggono. Mi sa (ma non sono sicura) che "ormai" si usa soprattutto in frasi che esprimono qualcosa di inevitabile o di "irreversibile" in un certo senso (non sempre nel senso stretto della parola, ma col significato che è molto difficile ritornare allo stadio precedente). Ad esempio, una delle domande su questo sito è

> [È «'sta» ormai italiano standard?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/2458/707)

La risposta afferma che "'sta" è adesso usuale nel parlato in tutta l'Italia, ma secondo me la presenza di "ormai" nella domanda significa che si ritiene difficile il ritorno a uno stato previo della lingua nel quale l'uso di "'sta" era geograficamente più ristretto.

Potreste spiegarmi le varie sfumature di significato e le differenze di uso tra questi vocaboli?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Adesso" si riferisce semplicemente al momento attuale (cfr. "ara", "ahora").

> Adesso andiamo al cinema.
>
> Adesso non posso, sto lavorando.

"Ormai" (o "oramai") contiene sempre un riferimento a qualcosa che si è concluso o sta per concludersi, a qualche cambiamento che è avvenuto o avverrà, o a qualche scadenza che è passata o sta per passare, e sottolinea le conseguenze o le condizioni che ne derivano.

> Sono già le 22, ormai (siccome sono le 22) è tardi per andare al supermercato.
>
> Sono due mesi che lavora a questo progetto, ormai (dato che ci lavora da due mesi) dovrebbe averlo completato.

Naturalmente si può anche usare senza premesse (che però sono implicite):

> Ormai non si trovano più libri di carta (sottinteso: dato che sono tutti ebook)

Si possono anche combinare "adesso" e "ormai", anche se suona un po' colloquiale e ridondante:

> Adesso ormai non funziona più (implica: tempo fa invece funzionava)

**Edit:** "ormai" si può anche usare in senso positivo:

> Ormai hanno superato le difficoltà iniziali (cioè: dopo un inizio difficile, sono arrivati al punto in cui ce l'hanno quasi fatta, manca poco affinché tutto vada bene).
>
> Ormai ho risolto il problema (cioè: non ho bisogno di ulteriore aiuto, smettete di aiutarmi/non aiutatemi più. Ma anche: l'ho quasi risolto/sono sul punto di risolverlo).

Answer (score 7):

**Ormai** si usa per indicare lo stato attuale, per esprimere il compimento di un processo, per sottolineare l’inevitabilità o l’irrimediabilità di una situazione, di un evento. Può avere anche accezione negativa per esprimere rassegnazione.

**Adesso** è un sinonimo di *ora*: può esprimere un momento passato da poco ma anche un evento che sta per accadere da un momento all'altro.

Fonti: [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/adesso/) e [Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/O/ormai.shtml)