# “Ora” vs. “adesso”. What are the differences?

Tags: word-usage, difference, adverbs

Quando si usa *ora* e quando *adesso*? 
Sembra che le due parole abbiano lo stesso significato. Ci sono differenze?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Does it matter if "now" is being used as a noun and not as an adverb? When would you like to go? "Now is good." Google Translate usually uses adesso but used ora in the above example; it only lists adesso as an adverb, but ora also as a noun.

Comment: @DaveD: Welcome to Italian.SE! Please use "Your Answer" box to write a real answer to the OP question. If you want to ask something, use "Ask Question" instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nowadays, they are mostly synonyms; for instance, the Treccani dictionary defines [*adesso*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/adesso/) as

> Sinon[imo] più com[une] e fam[iliare] di *ora*, spec[ialmente] nell’Italia settentr[ionale].

(A more common and familiar synonym of *ora*, especially in Northern Italy.)

However, nineteenth century writer and lexicographer [Niccolò Tommaseo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccol%C3%B2_Tommaseo), who had a very sensitive ear for shades of meaning, gave these differences (§2920, s.v. “Quando”):

> *Adesso* accenna relazione più diretta al passato | Dante: «O gente, in cui fervore acuto adesso Ricompie forse negligenza e indugio Da voi per tiepidezza in ben far messo» |. *Ora* accenna il momento presente, o i momenti prossimi al presente, guardati in sé; *adesso* accenna il presente in paragone del tempo passato. *Prima usava l'ipocrisia della fede; adesso quella del dubbio.*
>   *Ora* indica anche un punto più breve.
>   Per rincalzo, dicono in Toscana: ora adesso; come dire: ora stesso.

(Summarising, Tommaseo feels that *adesso* was used especially when contrasting or comparing the present to the past, while *ora* while speaking just of the present. And *ora* would also refer to a shorter range of time.)

Comment: Grazie mille. To make things more complicated. What about ormai in this context? According to my knowledge ormai may be used interchangeably with ora and adesso, right?

Comment: @freefall: Have a look at [this question](http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3716/707) and its answers.